# Error clase vector_t C++

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un código de búsqueda binaria en un fichero, sin embargo, me está dando error en la clase `vector_t` que utilizo para crear un vector en el que he de buscar un número.

Este es el código donde hago la búsqueda binaria en un fichero aparte:

```
#pragma once 

#include<iostream>
#include "stack_v_t.hpp"
#include "vector_t.hpp"

using namespace AED;


int binary_search(vector_t<int>& v, int x){

  stack_v_t<int> pila(2 * v.get_sz()); //le paso el tamaÃ±o de vector, una pila con el doble para evitar desbordamientos
  int auxiliar = 0;

  pila.push(x);

  while (!pila.empty()) {

    int derecha = pila.top(); //el valor que hay en top se iguala a lo que hay en derecha, en pila, necesitas meterlo en pila,   lo sobreescribe para hacer otra vuelta
    pila.pop();

    int izquierda = pila.top(); // se borra el top, pero izquierda y derecha siguen teniendo lo que habia en el top
    pila.pop();





 if (izquierda > derecha) {return -1; }

    else {
      int c= (izquierda+derecha)/2;

      if (v[c] == x) {
    return c;
    }
      else if (x<v[c]){
       derecha = c-1;
       pila.push(derecha);
       pila.push(izquierda);


      }
      else if (x>v[c]){
       izquierda = c+1;

       pila.push(derecha);
       pila.push(izquierda);

     }

    }

  }

}
```

Bien, este es el main de este código , que está en otro fichero:

```
    #include<iostream>
#include "bs.hpp"


#include "vector_t.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace AED;

#define TAM 10


int main (void) {


   vector_t<int> array(TAM); //las constantes se pasan asÃ­ cuando son clases vector 
   int i=0;
   int buscado,x;


   for (i=0;i<TAM;i++){
     cout << "Introduzca el elemento " << i << endl;
     cin >> x;
     array[i]=x; // los guardo en v[i]
   }



   cout << "cual es elemento que busca? "<< endl;
   cin>> buscado;


     if (binary_search(array, buscado)) 

    {

       cout << "el elemento "<<buscado<<"ha sido encontrado "<<endl;
     }

     else{
       cout << " el elemento " << buscado << "NO ha sido encontrado "<< endl;

     }
     return 0;


}
```

Bien, corregí los errores que me salieron en `bs` y `main_bs`, pero el compilador me señala errores en `vector_t` y `stack_v_t`.

Estos son los errores que no entiendo:

```
In file included from bs.hpp:5:0,
                 from main_bs.cpp:2:
stack_v_t.hpp:16:3: error: vector_t does not name a type
   vector_t<T> v_;
   ^
stack_v_t.hpp: In constructor AED::stack_v_t<T>::stack_v_t(int):
stack_v_t.hpp:21:3: error: class AED::stack_v_t<T> does not have any field named 
   v_(max_sz),
   ^
stack_v_t.hpp: In member function T AED::stack_v_t<T>::top():
stack_v_t.hpp:33:11: error: v_ was not declared in this scope
    return v_[top_];
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cassert:43:0,
                 from stack_v_t.hpp:7,
                 from bs.hpp:5,
                 from main_bs.cpp:2:
stack_v_t.hpp: In member function void AED::stack_v_t<T>::push(T):
stack_v_t.hpp:44:18: error:  was not declared in this scope
    assert(top_ < v_.get_sz() - 1);
                  ^
In file included from bs.hpp:5:0,
                 from main_bs.cpp:2:
stack_v_t.hpp: In member function std::ostream& AED::stack_v_t<T>::write(std::ostream&):
stack_v_t.hpp:53:34: error: v_ was not declared in this scope
     cout <<  << setw(2)<< v_.get_v(i) << << endl;
```

La clase `stack_v_t` me la proporcionan, también `vector_t`:

se que es mucho codigo, pero para ser conciso aqui os lo dejo:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
namespace AED {

    template <class T>
    class stack_v_t{
    private:

        vector_t<T> v_;
        int         top_;

    public: 
        stack_v_t(int max_sz):
        v_(max_sz),
        top_(-1) {}

        ~stack_v_t(void) {}

        bool empty(void){
            return (top_ < 0);
        }

        T top(void){

            assert(!empty());
            return v_[top_];
        }

        void pop(void){

            assert(!empty());           
            top_--;
        }

        void push(T dato){

            assert(top_ < v_.get_sz() - 1);

            top_ ++;
            v_[top_] = dato;
        }

        ostream& write(ostream& os){

            for(int i = top_; i >= 0; i--)
                cout << " â”‚ " << setw(2)<< v_.get_v(i) << "  â”‚" << endl;
            cout << " â””â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”˜" << endl; 
        }

    };
}
```

Esta es `vector_t`

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
namespace AED {

    template <class T>
    class vector_t{
    private:
        T*      v_;
        int     sz_;

    public:

        vector_t(int sz):
            v_(NULL),
            sz_(sz) {

            crea_vector();
        }

        ~vector_t(void){

            destruye_vector();
        }


        int get_sz(void) const
        {
            return sz_;
        }

        T operator[](int pos) const{

            assert((pos < sz_) && ((pos >= 0)));

            return v_[pos];
        }

        T& operator[](int pos){

            assert((pos < sz_) && ((pos >= 0)));

            return v_[pos];
        }

        ostream& write(ostream& os) const{

            os << setw(5) <<  sz_ << endl;
            os << endl;

            for(int i = 0; i < sz_; i ++){
                v_[i].write(os);
                os << " ";
            }

            return os;
        }


    private:

        void crea_vector(void){
            v_ = new T[sz_];
        }

        void destruye_vector(void)
        {
            if (v_ != NULL){
                delete [] v_;
                v_ = NULL;
            }
        }



    };


    template <>
    ostream& vector_t<int>::write(ostream& os) const{

        for(int i = 0; i < sz_; i ++)
            os << setw(4)  << v_[i] << " ";


        return os;
    }   

}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const AED::vector_t<int>& v)
{
    v.write(os);

    return os;
}
```

Se agradece ayuda, gracias

Comment: mire si tiene que incluir en `stack_v_t` vector_t `#include "vector_t.hpp"`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In file included from bs.hpp:5:0,
                 from main_bs.cpp:2:
stack_v_t.hpp:16:3: error: vector_t does not name a type
   vector_t<T> v_;
   ^
```

Si revisamos el fichero de cabecera `stack_v_t.hpp` vemos lo siguiente:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
// (1)

using namespace std;
namespace AED {

    template <class T>
    class stack_v_t{
    private:

        vector_t<T> v_; // (2)
```

En (2) haces uso de la clase `vector_t`, pero en (1) no figura ningún `#include` que incorpore la declaración de dicha clase a este fichero, luego el compilador no sabe nada acerca de esta clase (ni cuanto ocupa en memoria, ni como se usa, ni a qué constructor debe llamar, ...)

La solución es tan sencilla como incluir la cabecera que te falta:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include "vector_t.hpp" // ... o como se llame el fichero

// ...
```