# Duda ejercicio pila basada en listas

Tags: c++, lista, pilas

Encontré un ejercicio resuelto donde se usan pilas y listas que me generó dudas, es este:

> Impleméntese   el  método  no  recursivo   de  la  clase   `dll_t  ostream&    write_reverse (dll_node_t<T>*   n,  ostream&   os) const`  que muestra en  orden   inverso el  contenido   de  la  lista   enlazada    invocante   a   partir  del nodo    n   con 
>   ayuda de  una pila    que almacene    punteros    de  nodos.  Sólo    se  podrá   utilizar    el  método  `dll_node_t*    get_next()` de  la  clase    `dll_node_t`   para    acceder al  elemento    siguiente.  En  ningún  caso    se  permitirá   utilizar    el  método  `dll_node_t*    get_prev()`.

El ejercicio resuelto:

```
 template <class T>
  ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {      

        stack_v_t<dll_node_t<T>*> stack;

        while (n != NULL) {
            stack.push_back(n);
            n = n->get_next();
        }

        while(!stack.empty()){

            stack.top()->write(os);
            stack.pop();
        }

        return os;
    }

    template <class T>
    ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(ostream& os) const {

        reverse2(head_, os);

        return os;
    }
```

la clase pila de la que hace uso:

```
template <class T>
class stack_v_t{
private:
vector_t<T> v_;
int top_;
public:
stack_v_t(int max_sz);
~stack_v_t(void);
bool empty(void);
T top(void);
void pop(void);
void push(T dato);
};
```

Mi duda: Al crear la pila, ¿no debería tener un tamaño fijo, no le da un tamaño, tendría que tenerlo no?

Comment: [Repetida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89894/cuesti%c3%b3n-ejercicio-listas-c).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Una pregunta,si en vez de mostrar en orden inverso el contenido de la lista, lo quiero mostrar en orden normal, ¿cómo he de manejar la pila para que lo imprima así?

Comment: Las pilas no están diseñadas para ser atravesadas en ningún orden, su cometido es apilar o desapilar datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debería tener un tamaño fijo,
La implementacion no tiene un constructor `stack_v_t()` sin parametros asi que segun esa implementacion de pila la respuesta esta mal.

```
template <class T>
class stack_v_t{
private:
vector_t<T> v_;
int top_;
public:
stack_v_t(int max_sz);//Constructor
//Necesitaria n constructor:stack_v_t();
~stack_v_t(void);
bool empty(void);
T top(void);
void pop(void);
void push(T dato);
};
```

El tamaño fijo se debe a una limitacion de la  implementacion no que el concepto de pila lo requiera. Si se implementa con arrays el tamaño puede ser importante pero si se implementa con listas enlazadas no.

El metodo tiene fallos que no inicia la clase pila:

```
 template <class T>
  ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {      

        stack_v_t<dll_node_t<T>*> stack;
        /*stack no es un puntero es un stack del   tipo  
          stack_v_t<dll_node_t<T>*> 
          al inicializarse asi  la clase stack_v_t debe tener un 
          constructor sin parametros y las llamadas a los metodos se 
          hacen con '.' en lugar de ->
         */

        while (n != NULL) {
            stack.push_back(n);
            n = n->get_next();
        }

        while(!stack.empty()){

            stack.top()->write(os);//stack.top() devuelve un objeto 
            // tipo  T como se garantiza que tenga el metodo ->write(os)???
            //Puede ser?: os<<stack.top();
            stack.pop();
        }

        return os;
    }

    template <class T>
    ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(ostream& os) const {

        reverse2(head_, os);

        return os;
    }
```

Si la clase de pila que usas es la de esta otra pregunta [Error clase vector_t C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66202/error-clase-vector-t-c)
si creas un stack para 20 elementos no puedes usarlo para 21, pero es la implementacion la que es pobre, ya que al sobrepasar la capacidad deberia redimencionar el array y lo que hace es dar error.

Segun esta implementacion (el codigo no esta probado):

```
const int STACK_CAPACITY= 100;//maxima capacidad de la pila
 template <class T>
  ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const   {      

    stack_v_t<dll_node_t<T>*> stack(STACK_CAPACITY);

    while (n != NULL) {
        stack.push_back(n);
        n = n->get_next();
    }

    while(!stack.empty()){

        stack.write(stack.top());//Cambie aqui usando el metodo write de la clase stack_v_t
        stack.pop();
    }

    return os;
}

template <class T>
ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(ostream& os) const {

    reverse2(head_, os);

    return os;
}
```